# webapi No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action

the webapi route configs is the default:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

my webapi controller is like this

```
public class GapController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]       
    public static List<GapList> SelectGapList() {
        return GapListBusiness.SelectGapList();         
    }
}
```

this webapi is very easy, and the code like this app, my another app works!

if you konw what's wrong, please tell me, thank you!

Comment: Don't use static in the web api method.

Comment: I'v find the problem after work. 
I'm too careless.